# Sum string length of all array values

Tags: php, arrays, sum, concatenation, strlen

```
<?php
setcookie("Auction_Item", "Luxury Car", time()+2*24*60*60); 
if(isset($_COOKIE["Auction_Item"])){ 
    echo "Auction Item is a  " . $_COOKIE["Auction_Item"]; 
} else{ 
    echo "No items for auction."; 
} 
?>
```

Okay so this php code simply sets a cookie and gives the value, I need to write a function that after accepting a boolean parameter as TRUE returns the sum of length of all cookies presented into the request.

```
if ($val = true){
    $cookies = $_COOKIE
    $strVal = "";
    $countVal = count($cookies);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $countVal; $x++) {
        $strVal = $strVal . $cookies[$x].$val
    }
    echo 'Sum of length of all cookie values' . strlen($strVal)
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from MaryNfs is correct but missing one important thing from your original code.  Try the following:

```
setcookie("Auction_Item", "Luxury Car", time()+2*24*60*60); 
if(isset($_COOKIE["Auction_Item"])){ 
    echo "Auction Item is a  " . $_COOKIE["Auction_Item"]; 
} else { 
    echo "No items for auction."; 
} 

$val = true;  //Set the variable $val

//You had $val = true, setting $val to true.  
//You need to evaluate it as true or false so use === to compare
//Using = sets the variable's value

if($val===true) {    
    $joinedCookies = "";    
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$value) {
        $joinedCookies = $joinedCookies . $value;
    }
    $joinedCookiesLength = strlen($joinedCookies);
    echo 'Sum of length of all cookie values ' . $joinedCookiesLength;
}
```

Once the `$_COOKIE` is set, the above should return:

> Auction Item is a Luxury Car
>
> ---
>
> Sum of length of all cookie values 36

Your code was missing `;` after three lines which would break things so keep an eye out for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

To get the total string length of a flat array, `implode()` the elements using no glue, then call `strlen()`.

No manual looping, no manual concatenation, and no temporary variables.

```
echo strlen(implode($_COOKIE));
```

Answer (score 0):

if I got it right, you can get the length of all cookie values like this:

```
$joinedCookies = "";    
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$value){
    $joinedCookies = $joinedCookies.$value;
}
echo 'Sum of length of all cookie values: '.strlen($joinedCookies);
```